# Why does the rule for multiplication/division take into consideration the no. of significant figures?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I've learned that the rule for multiplication, when taking into account the significant figures, is as follows:

The final result should retain as many significant figures as there are in the original number with the least significant figures.

So, by that definition, if I has the mass of an object `= 4.237g` and  its volume `= 2.51 cm^3`, then the density would be `1.69 g cm^-3`. However, let's take an example in which we have the side of a cube given to be `25.6` which has 3 significant figures. Now let's find out its volume: `16777.216`. Now if I wanna report my result with the least significant figures (3), I would get an answer `168` which is plain wrong.

I could use scientific notation, but even there, I would have the significant figures which are *significant.*

Could someone help me out by explaining me this rule's implication? Thanks.

Comment: related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8914/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14820/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now let's find out its volume: 16777.216. Now if I wanna report my result with the least significant figures (3), I would get an answer 168 which is plain wrong.

Your problem is that you seem to be *truncating* the value! When employing the significant figure rule, **you turn all other values to *zero***. [Trailing zeros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figure) are placeholders, so they can be eliminated from the reported value *when using scientific notation*. If you are *not* using scientific notation, you must record those zero's:
$$
16777.216 \Rightarrow 16800\neq168
$$
As compared to the scientific notation form,
$$
1.6777216\times10^4 \Rightarrow 1.6800000\times10^4\equiv1.68\times10^4
$$